# In symfony2 how do I add nullable boolean

Tags: symfony

I'm using FOSRestBundle and am trying to setup a POST that will allow null to ba saved for a few fields defined as checkbox in the FormType.

My entity has the annotation nullable=true

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
protected $foo_bar;
```

The FormType (which will only ever be used through the API so it's mostly left to the deaults) has required set to false

```
$builder->add('foo_bar', 'checkbox', array(
    'required' => false
));
```

When I save and foo_bar is null, it saves as 0 in the database

```
$entityData = $request->request->all();
$entityData['foo_bar'] = null;
$entity = $this->container->get('acme.entity.handler')->post($entityData);
```

I need to save foo_bar as null (not answered), rather than 0 (answered false)

(the handler is from here http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/ it's just validating the data POSTed against the formtype then persisting)

edit:
I'm not sure that FormTypes can handle a nullable boolean. Tests based on the responses to this question either save false as null or null as false. For now I've decided to stop using the handlers as described in the linked post and instead validate manually then persist directly with the entity manager.

Comment: how would you tell the difference between ... false, and not answered...

Comment: Could you show `explain table_name` for the table in which the foo_bar column exists?

Comment: explain > "foo_bar | tinyint(1) | YES | MUL | NULL" so doctrine created it correctly

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox by it's nature can only have 2 states, true or false. So not selecting it would only ever be seen as false as opposed to not answered.

I would say the easiest way to achieve what you are after is to use a choice field with `true` and `false` as options and an empty value added.

```
$builder->add('foo_bar', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'required'      => false,
    'choices'       => array(
        'Yes'       => true,
        'No'        => false,
    ),
    'empty_value'   => 'Not Answered',
));
```

The text can be what ever you want as you are using it in an API rather than a direct form but I guess it makes the values more explicit when you look at it.

Comment: how would this render when i want to edit the entry?

Comment: It would default to `Not Answered` (providing the underlying value is null on load) and have the choices of `Yes` (true) and `No` (false). As the OP is creating a REST API the actual text is not necessary as validation wouldn't use it, but for reusability it makes sense to have it just incase they ever wished to use it in a regular form.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but how would this look visually to the user? yes = checked, no = unchecked, and not answered = ?? (unchecked?!) that would be confusing

Comment: The choice field is a select box/drop-down not a checkbox.

Comment: I am only building the formtype to validate against (this is to handle a RESTful POST & PUT), so maybe it should just by an integer.

Comment: 1 & 0 should map to true and false. The drop-down/select is just a view. Essentially you want to provide 3 choices (null, 1/true and 0/false) so you should use a ChoiceType.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a checkbox is not the the form field type you need, maybe you need to use a drop-down with 'yes', 'no', 'no answer'

a checkbox by definition can hold one of two values either true or false, you could do some weird stuff in the controller by setting the field to null and then not displaying the checkbox field to the user, but that would break the 'separation of concerns' guideline, but if you absolutely have to use a checkbox, then its gona get messy

Comment: I am only building the formtype to validate against (this is to handle a RESTful POST & PUT), so maybe it should just by an integer

Comment: like @qooplmao said, 1, 0, and null would be the data stored on the DB